# Prevent the code to be seen inside Iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I wonder if it is possible to prevent the code to be seen inside the Iframe? IE 11 shows the sources code immediately when you select this option from an iframe page...
Dave

Comment: Any code you send to the client will be viewable by anyone with half a clue. Always assume that. Best you can do is obfuscate the code so it's illegible.

Comment: how can I do that?is there an obfuscator for that purpose?

Comment: Many. Can't name one off the top of my head, but obfuscating/minimizing is a common practice. A google search h should turn up your best options.